# Failed to get FIS auth token

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.m.i(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.m.a(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:8)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.o.h(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.0:11)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.o.i(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.0:1)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.o.d(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.0:1)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.y(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.0:1)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.l.start(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.v.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.0:8)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.z(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.0.0:5)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.i.then(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.s.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.q.c.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
    at com.google.firebase.installations.g.g(FirebaseInstallations.java:10)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.g.s(FirebaseInstallations.java:1)
    at com.google.firebase.installations.f.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
```

But this error is not getting in Signed APK. Error occurs only in playstore build.